# Can I use complex Gaussian random variables in Mathematica?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random

I have been looking for complex Gaussian random variables and Mathematica, however, I haven't found anything on this topic.

Could someone, please, let me know if it is possible to find for example the expectation of a complex Gaussian random variable with Mathematica?

Comment: What have you tried? It's unclear what you're asking: the usual way of specifying such a distribution would have the expectation as input.

Comment: You can create a random variable using RandomVariate[] and you can find the expectation using Expectation[]...

Answer (score 1):

Just use two-dimesional Gaussian random variables and convert them to complex ones. E.g., you may use the following to generate random samples from the "complex" normal distribution:

```
μ = {0, 0};
Σ = IdentityMatrix[2];
n = 10;
rand = RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[μ, Σ], {n}].{1., 1. I}
```

You can slso use `ReIm` to convert from complex numbers back to points in the Euclidean plane.

Comment: That's generation of random variates, but it doesn't address the original question, which is finding the expectation value of something.

Comment: Yeah, I know. It's more a comment with code and a way to make the OP think about the conversion between points in the plane and complex numbers...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, please, have a look at this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171186/find-mathbbe-left-frac-textbfhh-textbfy-textbfyh-textbfh.